# V8 on Android. ndk-build throws "error: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()' is protected"

Tags: android, android-ndk, v8

I am currently following the tutorial, http://lorinbeer.github.io/tutorial/2013/04/19/vatedroid-p2-linking-v8.html. The series of blog article is very useful for me to run V8 on Android applications. I successfully compiled V8 library without error. However, I failed to run ndk-build command with the below error:

```
handk@handk-ubuntu:~/devel/androidWorkspace/vatedroid-tutorial$ ndk-build
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: vatedroid <= vatedroid.cpp
jni/../include/v8.h: In function '_jstring* Java_com_vatedroid_VateDroidActivity_feedVatedroid(JNIEnv*, jobject, jstring, jstring)':
jni/../include/v8.h:832:13: error: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()' is protected
jni/vatedroid.cpp:26:17: error: within this context
jni/vatedroid.cpp:28:48: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Context::Scope::Scope(v8::Persistent<v8::Context>&)'
jni/vatedroid.cpp:28:48: note: candidates are:
jni/../include/v8.h:5882:24: note: v8::Context::Scope::Scope(v8::Handle<v8::Context>)
jni/../include/v8.h:5882:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'v8::Persistent<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Handle<v8::Context>'
jni/../include/v8.h:5880:9: note: v8::Context::Scope::Scope(const v8::Context::Scope&)
jni/../include/v8.h:5880:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'v8::Persistent<v8::Context>' to 'const v8::Context::Scope&'
jni/vatedroid.cpp:32:28: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
jni/vatedroid.cpp:33:28: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
jni/../include/v8.h: In function 'void Java_com_vatedroid_VateDroidActivity_initVatedroid(JNIEnv*, jobject)':
jni/../include/v8.h:832:13: error: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()' is protected
jni/vatedroid.cpp:69:17: error: within this context
jni/vatedroid.cpp:73:47: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Context::New(NULL, v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>&)'
jni/vatedroid.cpp:73:47: note: candidate is:
jni/../include/v8.h:5784:25: note: static v8::Local<v8::Context> v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)
jni/../include/v8.h:5784:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>' to 'v8::ExtensionConfiguration*'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/vatedroid/vatedroid.o] Error 1
```

I think ***error: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()' is protected*** is the main symptom of the error, but have no idea how to deal with it since I am not a C/C++ expert.

FYI, I put V8 libraries that I compiled in /libs folder. Also, I copied all headers from recent V8 git repository. I upload the files in jni directory as below:

#### Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8_base
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/libv8_base.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := v8_nosnapshot
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  ../libs/libv8_nosnapshot.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := vatedroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := vatedroid.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := v8_base v8_nosnapshot
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

#### vatedroid.h

```
#ifndef _VATEDROID_H
#define _VATEDROID_H

#include <jni.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <android/log.h>

/**
 * execute a script from native
 */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    jstring Java_com_vatedroid_VateDroidActivity_feedVatedroid(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring name, jstring message);
/**
 * initialize the V8 execution environment for vatedroid scripts 
 */
    void Java_com_vatedroid_VateDroidActivity_initVatedroid(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // _VATEDROID_H
```

#### vatedroid.cpp

```
#include "vatedroid.h"
#include <string.h>

v8::Persistent<v8::Context> PrimaryContext;

/**
 *
 */
jstring Java_com_vatedroid_VateDroidActivity_feedVatedroid(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring name, jstring message) {
    using namespace v8;
    HandleScope scope;
    TryCatch tc;
    Context::Scope context_scope(PrimaryContext);
    jstring retval;
    jboolean isCopy;

    Handle< String > nme = String::New(env->GetStringChars(name, &isCopy));
    Handle< String > cmd = String::New(env->GetStringChars(message, &isCopy));

    Handle< Script > script = Script::Compile(cmd, nme);

    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "VATEDROID", "Compiled Scipt");

    if (script.IsEmpty()) {
        return env->NewStringUTF("Error: Bottle is empty!");
    }

    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "VATEDROID", "Feeding Vatedroid");

    Local< Value > result = script->Run();

    if (result.IsEmpty()) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "VATEDROID", "RESULT IS EMPTY");
        String::Utf8Value error(tc.Exception());
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "VATEDROID", *error);
    }
    String::Utf8Value retstr(result);
    retval = env->NewStringUTF(*retstr);
    return retval;
}

/**
 *
 */
 void Java_com_vatedroid_VateDroidActivity_initVatedroid(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    // log what's happening
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "VATEDROID NDK", "INITIALIZING VATEDROID");
    // can be placed at any scope resolution level, this will be redeclared in any V8 aware function 

    using namespace v8;

    // create the scope and context
    // governs local handles
    HandleScope localscope;
    // object template used to create the global object of our context
     Local< ObjectTemplate > global = ObjectTemplate::New();
    // declaration and instantiation of the primary context
    PrimaryContext = Context::New(NULL, global);
}
```

Comment: I tried to put "*using namespace v8;*" in vatedroid.cpp. But doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which version of the V8 API you're using, it's possible that you've been bitten by a rather major API change that was not very well-documented, and in fact the current documentation still refers to the old API.

In creating your context you should have a `v8::Isolate*` which reflects the actual VM instance.  When you create a `HandleScope`, you must pass in this `Isolate` object as its argument, e.g.:

```
v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
```

Pretty much every V8 API call now requires you to explicitly pass in this isolate.  And, unfortunately, the documentation makes absolutely no indication of this, nor are any of the publicly-built V8 Doxygen sites up-to-date either.